# Identify rows in a dataframe that only have NA

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df`

```
A    B
x    y
x    NA
NA   NA
```

I want to create a new column, say `df$C`, that has value 0 if that row only contains NA and 1 otherwise. My desire `df` is

```
A    B    C
x    y    1
x    NA   1
NA   NA   0
```

Really appreciate any help

Comment: quick and dirty: `df$C = rowSums(is.na(df)) == 0`

Comment: @MichaelChirico It does not work, it returns 1, 0, 0 instead of 1, 1, 0

Comment: This is why you need to [provide a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The code works if `df[2, 'B']` is _actually_ `NA`, which it appears it is not.

Comment: To get 1, 1, 0, surely just tweak @MichaelChirico 's answer to `df$C = as.numeric(rowSums(is.na(df)) != 2)` (where 2 is the number of columns in `df`, excluding C). So you get 0 if all the entries in a row are `NA`, and 1 otherwise.

Comment: and a bit more generic: `df$C <- as.integer(rowSums(is.na(df)) != ncol(df))`